# Let $f=\sum_{j,k}f_{j,k}Y_{j,k}$, what would be the expansion of $f^2$ on spherical harmonics $Y_{j,k}$?

Tags: exponentiation, harmonic-analysis, spherical-coordinates, harmonic-functions, spherical-harmonics

Let $f :S^{n-1}\longrightarrow R_+$ be a square integrable function.
Let $\{Y_{j,k}\}$ be an orthonormal basis of spherical harmonics on $S^{n-1}$, $j\in Z_+$ and $k=1, \ldots, d_n(j)$, where $d_n(j)$ is the dimension of the subspace of spherical harmonics of degree $j$.

Consider expansion of $f$ on spherical harmonics:
$$f=\sum_{j,k}f_{j,k}Y_{j,k},$$
where $f_{j,k}$ are Fourier-Laplace coefficients of $f$.

What would be the expansion of $f^2$ on spherical harmonics $Y_{j,k}$?